# How to post URL on friend's Facebook wall?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, facebook-c#-sdk

I am creating Windows 8 app with C#/XAML. I want to share URL to logged in user's friend. Facebook has removed [**ability to post to friends walls via Graph API** after 6th Feb, 2013](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/). Facebook recommends to use [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/), but that dialog can be used with the JavaScript, iOS, and Android SDKs ONLY.

So how can I achieve this in WinRT ?

**UPDATE 1**

I found there's one more thing available that's URL Redirection. So I need to use WebView (which is one of worst control in WinRT) temporarily to open that URL and user will press "share". This way kills the UI/UX :(

**UPDATE 2**

I tried to use the URL Redirection, but I am getting error stating "An error occurred. Please try later". I searched about that, I tried all the ways like sandbox mode, double checking app ID but nothing worked for me. When I use app ID of graph api explorer it works.

Working

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=145634995501895&display=popup&link=http://stackoverflow.com&name=Stack Overflow&picture=http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png&redirect_uri=https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer&description=Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.&to=100000692924752

Not working

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=159248604260839&display=popup&link=http://stackoverflow.com&name=Stack Overflow&picture=http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png&redirect_uri=https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer&description=Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.&to=100000692924752

Comment: Do you still have a question? The API is documented well, and as there is no official WinRT Facebook SDK. Does the one from the Outercurve foundation have what you need?

Comment: @ WiredPrairie :D I am sad why Facebook is not thinking to support W8

Comment: Demand. Further, if the open source SDK is sufficient for most, why doubly invest? Also, if there isn't an official app yet, then I can see why they wouldn't have an official SDK. http://thenextweb.com/microsoft/2013/06/26/confirmed-official-facebook-app-is-coming-to-windows-8/